# If statement for multiple conditions

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm working on a script that forwards mails IF recipient, sender and subject are right. For ex.

Mail is forwarded if all are true:

- From: OneGuy@mail.com
- To: OtherGuy@mail.com
- Subject: Hallo `Or` Hi

This is my current script

```
Public Sub FW(olItem As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
Set Msg = Item

    If Msg.SenderEmailAddress = "OneGuy@mail.com" Then
    ElseIf Msg.To = "OtherGuy@mail.com" Then
    ElseIf Msg.Subject = "Hallo" Then
    ElseIf Msg.Subject = "Hi" Then

        Dim olForward As Outlook.MailItem
        Set olForward = olItem.Forward

        With olForward
            'Stuff happens here that work properly 
        End With

    End If    

    '// Clean up
    Set olItem = Nothing
    Set olForward = Nothing
    Set Msg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Cant you just set up an Inbox Rule for something so simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
If Msg.SenderEmailAddress = "OneGuy@mail.com" AND Msg.To = "OtherGuy@mail.com" AND Msg.Subject = "Hallo" AND Msg.Subject = "Hi" Then
```